# why cast the result of add(myButton) when assigning it to a Button array

Tags: java, button

here is the code section

```
    b1=new Button("yes");
    b2=new Button("no");
    b3=new Button("maybe");

    bList=new Button[3];
    bList[0]=(Button)add(b1);
    bList[1]=(Button)add(b2);
    bList[2]=(Button)add(b3);
```

b1,b2,b3 and bList[] are already declared .The question i am asking is that when bList is of type Button and b1/b2/b3 are of type Button why do i need to cast it to Button when assigning them to bList array?

Comment: How you create reference bList ??

Comment: How about `bList[0] = b1;`? What is `add()`?

Comment: From what class is the `add` method?  What does it return?

Comment: Are the button objects of type button or a more genric instance?

Comment: Please provide detail of add method

Comment: i dont know the detail of add method ,i need to know that too

Comment: It's your code.  `add` is called on `this` implicitly, so either show your `add` method or reveal which class you're extending that defines the `add` method for you.

Comment: I am extending Applet class,sorry for not mentioning it before

Comment: is it Applet class's method ,if yes why does it return a Component object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`add` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) you call is inherited from `Container`.  It takes a `Component`, adds it to itself, and returns the same `Component`, so the returned `Component` needs to be casted back to `Button`.

The cast is unnecessary if the line

```
List[0]=(Button)add(b1);
```

is broken into two statements (and made clearer).

```
List[0] = b1;
add(b1);
```

Answer (score 0):

All right i get it now . add() returns a component object .thats why wee need to cast it to Button type

Comment: but whos method is add() ?

Comment: Adding answer and asking question

Comment: yeah.whos method is add()